# Can I use in r the leaflet "map_shape_click" event to populate a box() with a datatable?

Tags: r, datatable, leaflet, shinydashboard

I have been searching the web for weeks trying to find an example or a code for what I am trying to accomplish with my shiny app (shinydashboard). I’m new to r and I’m starting to think that what I am trying to do is not possible.  I basically have a leaflet map with a county polygon (shapefile) and I want to use the click event on the polygon to open a related dataTable (species table) on a box() below the map. The polygon data is a shapefile containing the county name and county number id. The related dataTable contain the county name, county #id and names of species for each county (one-to-many relationship). I was thinking that some how I could use the observe function and county # id from the “map_shape_click” to render the table with the names of the species by county on a output box(). However I don’t know if that is even possible.  So far I was able to create the map and use the click event to capture the county name on a box() ( see attached image). 
This forum is amazing and I have learn a lot from the postings. Thank everyone that contribute to the community. If you have any suggestions how I can accomplish this task please let me know,
Thanks

JB

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgdD4.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

let see if I got it right..

You can get the desired result by capturing the info related to hte clicked polygon and then using the id to subset your table

```
library(raster)
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(DT)

#species per region
mydata<-data.frame(myID=c("Iburengerazuba", "Iburasirazuba","Umujyi wa 
Kigali","Umujyi wa Kigali", "Amajyaruguru", "Iburengerazuba", 
"Amajyaruguru", "Amajyaruguru"),
myspec=c("virginiana", "setosa", "barbosa", "pelosa",
"pudica","pudica","pudica","pudica"))

#load in shapefiles for state
states <- getData("GADM", country = "rwa", level = 1)

#define color palettes for states
statePal <- colorFactor("Dark2", states@data$NAME_1)


shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(
    leafletOutput('myMap', width = "100%"), 
    br(), 
    DT::dataTableOutput("mytable", width = "100%")
  ),

  server <- function(input, output, session){

    output$myMap <- renderLeaflet({
       leaflet() %>% 
        addTiles() %>% 
        addPolygons(data = states, 
                    fillColor = ~statePal(states@data$NAME_1), 
                    fillOpacity = 1, 
                    color = "white", 
                    stroke = T, 
                    weight = 1, 
                    layerId = states@data$NAME_1) 
    }) 

    observeEvent(input$myMap_shape_click, {

      #capture the info of the clicked polygon
      click <- input$myMap_shape_click

      #subset your table with the id of the clicked polygon 
      selected <- mydata[mydata$myID == click$id,]

      #if click id isn't null render the table
      if(!is.null(click$id)){
        output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
          selected
        }) 
      } 
    }) 
  })
```

Comment: Hello G. Cocca,

Comment: Hello G. Cocca, Thank you very much for the response...It is  exactly what I was trying to accomplish. It work great. The section to subset the layer id was not clear to me before. I did get it done using a similar observe event but your code is much clear. Thank once again for your help!                                                  
JB

Comment: Glad it was helpful!

Comment: @G.Cocca please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474422/in-r-leaflet-dont-reflect-the-latitude-nor-longitude?__=976320040